# Node.js: Multiple product line builds from one package.json

Tags: node.js, package.json, software-product-lines

We are building a Node.js app. As we are practicing Continuous Delivery with Trunk Based Development we would only have one branch and one build to work with.

For several reasons including legal requirements we are expected to deliver a patch version for the currently released version any time we are developing a next feature release. What's more: There are features and/or activities that would not make it to the next feature version.

Obviously any new features have to be excluded from the patch release, any we-will-not-make-the-next-feature-release stuff has to be excluded from the next release.

In order to test (and ship betas) we are building and testing three versions of the product, say 1.0, 1.1 and 1.2.

Exclusion of features is done using feature toggles.

Question: How could I exclude dependencies only valid for next feature release or even later from being put into the `node_modules` during build?

If it were for two lines I would try something using the optional dependencies of `package.json`.

Is there any other way to make sure:

- dependencies for 1.1 and after are not making it into 1.0
- dependencies for 1.2 and after are not making it into 1.0 and 1.1
- require(...) does not fail for not existing dependencies (wrapping with feature toggle???)

Is there a way to avoid keeping three `package.json`'s and pick the "just right" one during build of each version?

Comment: There is also the issue of dependency version changes to account for. This would be easily solved by using branches for patches that are merged into the development branch. Is there some reason you aren't doing that?

Comment: Thing is we just moved to trunk based approach for the predecessor product was developed in branches which caused so much trouble with late integration and late broken dependencies or plain broken features that we decided to go for the tbd this time, running an experiment sort of. Now we try to figure where this left us. This dependency thing is one of the findings. For Java micro services we handle this with maven means. We could do so here as well (multiple package json files). I was wondering whether or not there is a more "native" solution

Comment: The safest way to do this for an arbitrarily large number of versions is to create separate `package.json`s and copy the appropriate one into place when doing a build. `npm` doesn't support concurrent version dependencies, natively.